# Is there a way to stop execution in Java and start it again?

Tags: java, spring, cron

In my Java project, I'm using a cron that allows to retrieve a list of data and send emails. It is executed every midnight.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${alerts.scheduler.cron}")
private void sendAlertNotifications() throws MessagingException {

    alertService.getArticlesPerAlert(new Date())).forEach((k, v) -> {
        try {
            emailService.sendAlertsNotification(k.getFullName(), k.getEmailAddress(),
                    alertService.getMatchingArticlesByLang(v, "EN"),
                    alertService.getMatchingArticlesByLang(v, "FR"), baseUrl);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error while sending alert {} for the email {}", k.getAlertId(),
                    k.getEmailAddress());
        }
    });
}
```

The method getVacanciesPerAlert(Date date) returns a Map of an Alert object as a key (Contains the id, and the emails address). The value of the map is a list of articles that match the user criteria.

I need to change this method to send 50 mails every 15min instead of send all emails once.

My solution is to store data in DB, so instead of using emailService.sendAlertsNotification(), I'll insert informaiton in the DB. Then I use an other cron to get a list of 50 rows and call emailService.sendAlertsNotification().

The problem in this solution is that I have to call alertService.getArticlesPerAlert() at every execution to retrieve all data, and to filter if the alert has been sent or not (by using a flag).

Is there a way to stop the loop foreach after every 50 mails (50 iteration) and wait 15mins to continue the process until the the last iteration of the Map?

I'm not sure which solution is more performant for this task.

Thank you

Comment: ehm ... crontab? You can configure your application that it only handles x elements, and you can configure your crontab that your application is started every y minutes/hours/days/...

Comment: As Stultuske wrote just run your process every 15 minutes and only load and process up to 50 emails.

Comment: @Thomas i think that's not what he wants. He doesn't want it to run every 15 minutes throughout the day. He wants it to start at midnight, run for N 15 minute periods, then stop until the following midnight

Comment: @Michael you're probably right. In that case a java.util.Timer might be the way to go: load up to 50 emails, process them and if needed schedule another TimerTask after 15 minutes.

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments. The actual cron call a procedure that retrieves all data and it takes a lot of time to execute that is why I call it once at midnight. @Michael Is it safe to use a timer inside a foreach loop?

Comment: Timer is outdated. Use ScheduledExecutorService